# Dojo for date ((month/year) format

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

```
require(["dojo/date"], function(date){


var date1 = new Date("Feb 01, 2000")

}
```

we get the date in the format :- Tue Feb 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Now i want it in the format (month/year).

Answer (score 1):

Tue Feb 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0530  Formate if you want to set in DataPicker then you have write   java script Code

```
 dateStr="Tue Feb 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
  var fullDate = new Date(dateStr);
        var months = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
        var fullYear = fullDate.getFullYear()+"";
        var date = fullDate.getDate() +"-"+ months[fullDate.getMonth()] +"-"+ fullDate.getFullYear();

return date
```

and create dynamic date picker and set return date

```
 var props = {
        style:"{width :10em;}",
        promptMessage: "dd-mmm-yyyy",
        invalidMessage: "Date pattern should be DD-MMM-YYYY"
            };
         var w = new dijit.form.DateTextBox(props,ele);
              w.setDisplayedValue(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/bDPcd/

```
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale) {

    var date1 = new Date("Feb 01, 2000");

    var formatted = locale.format(date1, {
        selector: "date",
        datePattern: "MM/yy"       
    }); 
});
```